# Class, interface, or enum expected error

Tags: java, enums

I have tried just about everything I can think of to fix my error but I;m completely stumped. I keep getting a "class, interface, or enum expected" error. What am I missing?

```
import java.until.*;
public class FutureValues {
public static final Scanner CONSOLE = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Lab 3 written by JENNIFER ADAME");
System.out.println();
//declare variables
double p;
double r;
double y;
double f;

System.out.print("Enter present value: ");
double p = console.nextDouble( );
System.out.print("Enter interest rate: ");
double r = console.nextDouble( );
System.out.print("Enter number of years: ");
double y = console.nextDouble( );
double f = compoundInterest(p, r, y);
System.out.print("The future value is" + f);
}

public static double compoundInterest (double p, double r, double y) {
    double f = p * Math.pow(((1 + r) / 100), y); 
    return f;
   }
}
}
```

If anyone could help that would be awesome!

Comment: If you indented your code properly, the answer to your question would be obvious.  You have an extra `}` at the end of the file.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding one extra brace '}' at the end...just remove it

If wanna keep safe from these kind of errors in future,consider formatting your code properly.(Use Ctrl+shift+f for eclipse and Alt+shift+f for netbeans)

Answer (score 2):

There is a mismatched brace at the end of your file.